# I'm trying to get a property value of a non-object

Tags: php

this might sound like a duplicate but I have searched all topics about this here but still no luck... :(

I have this code:

```
$result = array();

include 'conn.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM editlistm WHERE checkvou IN (SELECT checkvou FROM editlist)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//$numRows = $result->count($rs);   
$numRows = $result->num_rows;


if ($numRows > 0) {
// output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        array_push($items, $row);
    }
    echo json_encode($items);
}
```

the conn.php:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbase = "cadacctg";

// Create connection 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbase);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

I dont see anything wrong but it keeps saying:

> 'Trying to get property of non-object in C:... on line 11' ($numRows = $result->num_rows;)

why is it that it is not considered an object? and what can i do about it?
thanks in advance :)

Comment: If the query call fails, `$result` will be `false`, and `false->num_rows;` doesn't work

Comment: ah i see thanks for the quick response :D i'll double check my sql code then, thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var_dump($result) before $numRows = $result->num_rows;
```

if this is false, then there is a problem in the query

Comment: thanks for this, double checking the sql code now, thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

Use the `fetch_object` or `fetch_array` to get the fields value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, this code:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

may fail.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

So you need do a check on it, like:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// For SELECT query, check if it's false
if (!$result) {
    exit('Query has failed.');
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, turns out i misspell the table name >.< thanks again :D

Comment: @fred Actually, a lot of problems can cause query gone wrong, like MySQL dropped connection etc. Something may just gone out of control. That's why you should always do that check.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your value is correct and is not falsey:

```
if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
     ///value returns not-false,
     $numRows = $result->num_rows; 
     ... 
}
else {
     //there is a problem with your SQL
}
```

this will only return a non-boolean-negative value for `$numRows` if the `->query` works correctly.

Comment: thanks :D just finished checking my query, turns out i misspell the table name >.< anyway it is fix now thanks again :D